# Почему этот ответ был удален как спам/оскорбительный?

Tags: поддержка, ответы, удаление-ответов, спам

Наткнулся на [вот этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1542427). Это выглядит вот так:

[image: раз]

В истории правок совершенно безобидное содержание:

> https://www.raylib.com/ Нашел, покрыла все нужды. Очень крутая вещь, советую!

Это известная библиотека, явно не какой-то хитрый пиар.

Почему ответ снесли как спам/оскорбление, а не просто как "не ответ"?

Comment: Потому что оно было помечено тревогой как спам, выглядело как спам и несоответствовало правилам оформления ответов. Всё что я сделал - одобрил тревогу, всё остальное произошло автоматически.

Comment: @aepot Это не [спам](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/2752075), флаг ошибочный. Такими темпами можно любой link-only answer приравнять к спаму.

Comment: @aepot Вообще за спам обычно прилетает [штраф в -100 репы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301304/353058) (хз почему тут не прилетел, возможно потому что модератор обработал флаг, а не система автоматически удалила вопрос за N спам-флагов). Получать такое за плохой ответ - это перебор, поэтому, имхо, поощрать неправильные флаги не надо.

Comment: Я переудалил ответ, проверьте, помечен ли он теперь как спам. Модератору контент ответа отображается всегда, поэтому я разницы не вижу.

Comment: @aepot Неа, надпись на ответе такая же, но теперь написано, что удалено чисто вами. Раз участнику штрафа не было, наверное без разницы, это я просто на будущее.

Comment: А теперь снялось?

Comment: @aepot Да, теперь норм.

Answer (score 3):

> Это известная библиотека, явно не какой-то хитрый пиар.

Не хитрый, но пиар... Это я отметил этот ответ тревогой как спам, так как он явно рекламный и от пользователя с низкой репутацией. При более подробном рассмотрении - да, правильнее было бы поставить тревогу "Не является ответом". Не против, если удаление отменят и вместо этого преобразуют в комментарий.